# How to autowire factorybean

Tags: java, spring

I have a ServiceListFactoryBean which creates a list of service implementations:

```
<bean id="services"
      class="org.springframework.beans...ServiceListFactoryBean"
      p:serviceType="ServiceInterface"/>
```

I can access the services using the applicationContext without a problem:

```
    final List services = ctx.getBean("services", List.class));
```

I can also use trad constructor-arg injection successfully:

```
<bean id="aClass" class="AClass">
    <constructor-arg ref="services"/>
</bean>
```

But if I try to autowire the dependency

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("services") private List services;
```

Then I get a `BeanCreationException` caused by

```
FatalBeanException: No element type declared for collection [java.util.List]
```

I am using Spring 3.0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is ...

```
@Resource(name="services") private List services;
```

Comment: This will indeed work, because now it is getting autowired by name, instead of by type. That was the case previously. May be you knocked the problem off this time. But you must understand why. So, please ponder over the answer provided. Cheers.

Comment: Vinegar -- There are only two beans in the whole project (so far) and regardless of using @Qualifiers or not, or explicitly seting default-autowire to byType or byName, @Autowiring doesn't work for this ServiceListFactoryBean.

Answer (score 4):

The exception message is from `DefaultListableBeanFactory`, and it's complining that it can't autowire your field because the `List` has no generic type (see `DefaultListableBeanFactory` line 716).

Try adding a generic signature to your field, e.h.

```
@Autowired @Qualifier("services") private List<Service> services;
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work I'm afraid. Explicitly set autowire to byType and get: 

    No matching bean of type [ServiceInterface] found for dependency [collection of ServiceInterface]

Answer (score 0):

what i actually found out today, is that when you need map of bean names to instances of specific interface, there is no need of `@Qualifier`'s and any sort of `FactoryBean` code. Spring would find and inject candidates for you. `@Resource` didn't do it's job, just in case.