# Spring autowire a list

Tags: spring, list, autowired

Is it possible to use `@Autowired` with a list?

Like I have properties file with mimetypes and in my class file I have something like this

```
@Autowired
private List<String> mimeTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: It's been a while - if any of the answers was helpful, please mark it as correct, so that others with the same question can easily identify any helpful answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)

Answer (score 67):

Spring 4 and older support the ability to automatically collect all beans of a given type and inject them into a collection or array.

Here is an example:

```
@Component
public class Car implements Vehicle {
}

@Component
public class Bus implements Vehicle {
}

@Component
public class User {
   @Autowired
   List<Vehicle> vehicles; // contains both car and bus
}
```

Ref: [Spring 4 Ordering Autowired Collections](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/spring-4-ordering-autowired-collections/)

Comment: what happens when there is no bean of that type defined? Will it autowire an empty list

Comment: @user2798694 It should be empty or null.

Comment: @user2798694, In my experience Spring will throw an exception about no beans found.  To get around this, wrap the collection in Optional when auto-wiring. Optional<List<Vehicle>>

Answer (score 34):

`@Qualifier("..")` is discouraged, instead try to *autowire-by-name* using

```
private @Resource(name="..") List<Strings> mimeTypes;
```

See also [How to autowire factorybean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153298/how-to-autowire-factorybean).

Comment: +1 Excellent find!  I was just trying to figure out why I couldn't get this scenario to work.

Answer (score 13):

You can even create a `java.util.List` within your spring .xml and inject this via `@Qualifier` into your application. From the springsource http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/xsd-config.html :

```
 <!-- creates a java.util.List instance with the supplied values -->
 <util:list id="emails">
   <value>pechorin@hero.org</value>
   <value>raskolnikov@slums.org</value>
   <value>stavrogin@gov.org</value>
   <value>porfiry@gov.org</value>
 </util:list>
```

So this would change your wiring to:

```
 @Autowired
 @Qualifier("emails")
 private List<String> mimeTypes = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I would suggest this approach since you're injecting a list of strings anyways.

cheers!

***EDIT***

If you want to inject properties, have a look at this [How can I inject a property value into a Spring Bean which was configured using annotations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317687/inject-property-value-into-spring-bean)

Comment: You forgot to add `mailto:prince.myshkin@idiot.org` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need a qualifier at minimum.  And the call to "new" seems contrary to the idea of using Spring.  You have Spring's role confused.  If you call "new", then the object isn't under Spring's control.

Comment: It just overwrites the whole object. Spring didn't know (or didn't care) that there was something there before.

Comment: Using prototype-scoped beans, you can even use the `new` and still have that bean spring managed btw http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Answer (score 0):

If the autowired bean is declared in the same (`@Configuration`) class and you need it to declare another bean, then following works:

```
@Bean
public BeanWithMimeTypes beanWithMimeTypes() {
    return new BeanWithMimeTypes(mimeTypes());
}

@Bean
public List<String> mimeTypes() {
    return Arrays.<String>asList("text/html", "application/json);
}
```

Naturally it behaves correctly even if you override the `mimeTypes` bean in another config. No need for explicit `@Qualifier` or `@Resource` annotations.

Comment: This is simply showing how to use a constructor (which is ok). But it needs to be pointed out that in this example there is not need to annotate mimeTypes() with @Bean unless you want its result available in the application context for some other reason than creating the BeanWithMimeTypes component.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to autowire it as long as the list is a bean. You'd then use the `@Qualifier` to tell Spring which bean/list to use. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: Wouldnt all beans of that type get autowired into the list?