# error springboot @autowired dependency

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I try do a fill repository with metrics in spring boot, but I have the problem that when I execute I recive error.

This is my error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actuatorMetricsPrinter' defined in file [ActuatorMetricsPrinter.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.util.Collection]: : No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:747)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1115)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
at hello.Application.main(Application.java:14)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics] found for dependency [collection of org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1118)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:919)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:811)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:739)
... 18 common frames omitted
```

And this is my code when I recive error:

```
    @Autowired
public DummyController(ActuatorMetricsPrinter metricsPrinter) {
    this.metricsPrinter = metricsPrinter;
}
```

I have a class ActuatorMetricsPrinter that show the metrics but I have a problem when try fill this repository

***EDIT ***

```
@Component
public class ActuatorMetricsPrinter {
private MetricRepository repository;

private static final String TEMPLATE = "Metric: %s [%s]";
private Collection<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics = null;

public String printAllMetrics() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (PublicMetrics pm : publicMetrics) {
        sb.append("Public Metric: " + pm.getClass().getName());
        sb.append("\n\n");

        for (Metric<?> m : pm.metrics()) {
            sb.append(String.format(TEMPLATE, m.getName(), m.getValue().toString()));
            sb.append("\n");
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

@Autowired
public void MetricExporterService(MetricRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}
```

And

```
@Controller
public class DummyController {

private final ActuatorMetricsPrinter metricsPrinter;

@Autowired
public DummyController(ActuatorMetricsPrinter metricsPrinter) {
    this.metricsPrinter = metricsPrinter;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/customMetrics", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String printMetrics() {
    return metricsPrinter.printAllMetrics();
}

@Bean
public ActuatorMetricsPrinter publicMetrics() {
    return new ActuatorMetricsPrinter();
}

}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you set @Component annotation on ActuatorMetricsPrinter class and configured scan path in spring?

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar Yes I have Component. What you refer with "configured scan path", it equal ComponenScan??. I have all in the same package

Comment: Are you using spring boot actuator?

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar Yes, I use spring boot Actuator

Comment: you have added Actuator dependency in maven or gradle file?

Comment: Yes, I have add this dependency

Comment: Can you try not to use @Autowired and specify an explicit mapping in Spring configuration, may be that will work. Although its weird, difficult to say what might be wrong.

Comment: Show your ActuatorMetricsPrinter code.

Comment: @ChirdeepTomar how make this?

Comment: @ci_ I edit with this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the actual problem is initializing the constructor for ActuatorMetricsPrinter.  You have it Autowired to take in a Collection so Spring is trying to find the set of PublicMetrics beans to use as a collection and it cannot find any. Here is the error in what you provided above that points to that.   I ran into the same issue myself at one point.

> No qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics] found for
>   dependency [collection of
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.PublicMetrics]: expected at
>   least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this
>   dependency.

From the [Spring Docs on Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html):

> In case of a Collection or Map dependency type, the container will
>   autowire all beans matching the declared value type. In case of a Map,
>   the keys must be declared as type String and will be resolved to the
>   corresponding bean names.

Since the PublicMetrics are not declared as beans I think the right way to do it is by autowiring to a MetricRepository. See [this link](http://kielczewski.eu/2015/01/application-metrics-with-spring-boot-actuator/) and the Exporting Metrics section there as a reference.  There is a link to a sample application. Here is some modified code that you can use.

```
@Autowired
public MetricExporterService(MetricRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

public String printAllMetrics() {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (Metric metric : repository.findAll()) {
        sb.append(String.format(TEMPLATE, metric.getName(), metric.getValue().toString()));
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I dont undestand. I need add this bean. But new element create PublicMetrics() that is this??

Comment: Mine was just a simple test without all of the actual classes you would use.  Yes I believe you would need to create beans for any of the PublicMetrics objects that you want to be included in your collection as being AutoWired in your construction.  I am not entirely sure if this is possible as the Spring Boot Actuator may not expose these as beans.

Comment: In looking at it a bit more I think the right way to do it is by autowiring to a MetricRepository.  See http://kielczewski.eu/2015/01/application-metrics-with-spring-boot-actuator/ as a reference with a sample application.  Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: I updated the answer to reflect some info above.  I have tried it myself and I get any metrics to do with services I have created but I don't get things like the container (Tomcat) or JVM metrics.  Are those the ones you were looking to export?

Comment: I get that run with your help. Thank you very much!. But I have a problem, because I want show system metrics that I obtained with actuator /metrics but if I change this code by publicMetrics type equals I put I recive java null pointer. What is the problem?? I edit the code

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about your null pointer problem as I don't quite  understand. Please post some code if you can.  In terms of the system metrics I have looked but don't see how they show up anywhere.  In the Spring Boot doc they mention that if you have Spring Messaging in your classpath that a MessageChannel is created for any event updates. I have not tried it but you can and see if that gets you the updates you want.   I will need to look some more to try and what is happening under the covers.

Comment: I see either that you don't have the constructor named right in ActuatorMetricsPrinter (you have MetricExporterService) or you are still using the public metrics.  Check out my fork of a Spring Actuator guide at https://github.com/rob-baily/gs-actuator-service and review that for what I did.  I also just tried autowiring a Collection<PublicMetrics> attribute and that worked as well.  Check out what I have at GitHub and see where yours might be different.  You might have some other configuration issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for you time. I prove your solution and go very good. Later I adapted for web services and I managed to make it work well. I have a doubt, because I need the anottation Service in the class?, if I delete this I recive error, but it isn´t a service because I delete scheduled and only excute when I call web services

Comment: Glad it worked for you.  You will either need to annotate your class with the [Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) annotation or set up a Bean definition for Autowiring to work.   The Service annotation allows the bean definition to be done via automatic class scanning.  I pushed a commit for an example of how it would work as a Bean definition to the GitHub link above.   There are multiple ways to define beans but in your can I think using the Service annotation would probably make the most sense.

Answer (score 2):

Spring beans factory not found a bean `Collection<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics` for autowarid; try to create a list of `PublicMetrics`
see :
 [Spring autowire a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267138/spring-autowire-a-list) 
[Auto-wiring a List using util schema gives NoSuchBeanDefinitionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363310/auto-wiring-a-list-using-util-schema-gives-nosuchbeandefinitionexception)