# How can I inject an instance of List in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ioc

## What works

Suppose I have a spring bean definition of an ArrayList:

```xml
<bean id="availableLanguages" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.Arrays" factory-method="asList">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <value>de</value>
                    <value>en</value>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Now I can inject this into all kinds of beans, e.g. like this:

```java
@Controller
class Controller {
    @Autowired
    public Controller(ArrayList<String> availableLanguages) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This works great.

## How it breaks

However if I change my controller a tiny bit and use the type `List` instead of `ArrayList` like this:

```java
@Controller
class Controller {
    @Autowired
    public Controller(List<String> availableLanguages) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then instead I get a list of all beans of type `String` rather then the bean I defined. However I actually want to wrap my List into an unmodifiable List, but this will only be possible if I downgrade my dependency to a list.

## So far discovered workaround

The following XML file:

```xml
<bean id="availableLanguages" class="java.util.Collections" factory-method="unmodifiableList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="java.util.Arrays" factory-method="asList">
            <constructor-arg>
                <list>
                    <value>de</value>
                    <value>en</value>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

works together with this controller:

```java
@Controller
class Controller {
    @Autowired
    public Controller(Object availableLanguages) {
        List<String> theList = (List<String>)availableLanguages;
    }
}
```

While this works the extra type cast is ugly.

## Findings so far

I figured that there is a [special handling for collections in Spring 4.2.5 (the currently most recent version)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/dd42a21f3968c165af924310fce460694803756f/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/DefaultListableBeanFactory.java#L1058) which seems to cause all the trouble. It creates special behaviour when a parameter is an interface that extends `Collection`. Thus I can workaround by using `Object` or a concrete implementation as parameter type.

## Question

Is there any way to directly inject a list into a bean? How?

Comment: You can use namespace `util`. Take a look in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring) asnwer.

Comment: @josivan: As far as I can see this would change the way how I define the list. However the definition of the list is not the problem. It is the injection that causes the problem or am I missing anything about what `util` does?

Comment: `util:list` is a regular bean in Spring context, you can inject it normally. I notice that you have a mix of Annotation and XML, then tray to use `@Qualifier` in constructor. For example `@Qualifier("myList")`

Comment: I'd use a concrete type like 'LanguageList'. I know this does not answer your question but it may solve your problem.

Comment: I had the same problem few days ago. Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267138/spring-autowire-a-list. Use `@Resource` annotation instead of `@Autowired`, it find beans but its name, not y type.

Answer (score 0):

Using @Qualifier will inject the bean with the given qualifier. You can name the list which you want to be a bean and that will work fine.