# Spring autowire a list of object with size

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am trying to create a list of my class object using @Autowire notation but I don't know how do I tell it the size.

For Example:

```
@Autowire
List<MyClassObject> listMyClassObject;
```

I observed that listMyClassObject always contains a single object. This behaviour is same as using like below

```
@Autowire
MyClassObject myClassObject;
```

My question is how do I specify a size for this list at runtime so that listMyClassObject is auto initialised with those many objects.I am trying to do this in spring boot

Comment: is MyClassObject a interface or super class? If yes how many implementation classes or sub classes do u have?

Comment: As far as I know, this should work `@Autowired List<MyClassObject> listMyClassObject`. Do you really have multple spring components of that type?

Answer (score 0):

Spring will inject *all beans* of type `MyClassObject` in your first example.

Spring will inject *the only* bean of type `MyClassObject` in your second example. This will fail if there are more than one (or no) bean of that type in your application context.

You probably have exactly one bean of type `MyClassObject` in your application context, which is why both examples seem to behave the same.

If you want a `List` with *at most* `n` elements of type `MyClassObject` you will have to let Spring inject all of them (like in your first example) and then truncate the list programmatically, which might look something like this

```
public List<MyClassObject> getMyClassObjects() {
    return listMyClassObject.stream().limit(10).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: How can I truncate that list when that list itself contains just 1 object?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - the code snippet I provided will return a list with _at most_ 10 entries. If there is only 1 element in the list, the result's size will still be 1.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't need to know the size to inject your dependencies in a list.

As shown in @Thoq's answer here :
[Spring autowire a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267138/spring-autowire-a-list)

> ```
> @Component
> public class Car implements Vehicle {
> }
>
> @Component
> public class Bus implements Vehicle {
> }
>
> @Component
> public class User {
>    @Autowired
>    List<Vehicle> vehicles;//contains car and bus
> }
> ```

Having multiple beans of the required type is properly working with a List injection.

It looks like you would only have a single bean of  this type. Can you provide your beans declarations ?